# Define 11 months and 26 days legally from June 6th 2015

Tags: rental-property

I am currently moving out of a rented property. We assumed we had til the 1st July 2016 but were notified we were to return keys by today at 12. Our contract states the tenancy lasts for 11 months and 26 days. What date would this be legally?

Comment: Something is wrong with your dates. 11 months and 26 days is less than a year. Less than a year from June 6th would be sometime in early June or perhaps end of May again. And please change "today" to the actual date, so that it makes sense to people reading this next week.

Comment: Use [this](https://www.timeanddate.com/date/dateadd.html) calculator. Either way, the best thing you can do is talk to the landlord. Tell them that they are incorrectly calculating your last day, that your last day is July 1, and you will be out by close of business on that day. If you are in the US, there is no practical and legal way they can force you out before that date, even if they are right about the date and you are wrong. You could also try negotiating a cash deal to get you out early. But make it clear that leaving today would be early.

Answer (score 1):

Eleven months from June 6 is May 6 of the next year, in any year: it doesn't matter how many days are in a particular month, you just add 1 to the month until you've done that 11 times. 26 days from May 6 is June 1. Given that today is June 30, technically you should have been out almost a month ago, unless you misread the initial date and it was actually July 6.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the correct starting date is **July** 6, 2105. Actually, that would begin at "mid-night," July 5, 2015, going into July 6, 2015.

Eleven months from that date is midnight June 5-6th. Twenty six days from that would be  mid night "June 31st" except there is no June 31st of any year. So the end date would be July 1, 2016, midnight, going into July 2nd.

You had the lease until the end of July 1. The confusion may have arisen from the fact that July has 31 days and June doesn't. So a lease starting August 6, 2015 would indeed end at midnight July 31, 2016, and not on August 1, 2016.